# one hot encoding many columns of mixed data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set of mixed types that need to be converted to numerical while still retaining the information from the character type data. My current solution is in R, but I need to convert it to Python now given the person who will receive this script doesn't know or want to transition towards learning R, which is understandable. Is it possible to achieve this in Python using the Pandas library? And if so, how does one achieve this?

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

dat <- data.table(x = c('No Data', '2', 'Testing', 'Offline'),
                  y = c('2', 'No Data', '4', 'Testing'),
                  z = c(1, 2, 3, 6))

select_cols <- c('x','y')

dat[, paste0(select_cols,'_no_data') := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(str_detect(x, 'No Data'))), .SDcols = select_cols]
dat[, paste0(select_cols,'_offline') := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(str_detect(x, 'Offline'))), .SDcols = select_cols]
dat[, paste0(select_cols,'_testing') := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(str_detect(x, 'Testing'))), .SDcols = select_cols]

dat[, paste0(select_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) str_replace(x, 'No Data|Offline|Testing', '0')), .SDcols = select_cols]
dat[, paste0(select_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(x)), .SDcols = select_cols]

dat
```

*edit: print out raw and preprocessed data*

```
 x        y          z 
 No Data  2          1 
 2        No Data    2 
 Testing  4          3 
 Offline  Testing    6
```

```
x    y    z   x_no_data   y_no_data   x_offline   y_offline   x_testing   y_testing  
0    2    1           1           0           0           0           0           0  
2    0    2           0           1           0           0           0           0  
0    4    3           0           0           0           0           1           0  
0    0    6           0           0           1           0           0           1
```

Comment: Maybe you can show your raw data table (or a reasonable number of rows), and your desired outcome... makes it much easier for people to help you out with it

Comment: Sorry, I don't have R studio and I can't run your code. Can you please show me your data `print(dat)` and expected output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, the main part of it is [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), which does the one-hot encoding for you, and the [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method with the argument `errors = "coerce"` alters your original `x` and `y` columns in the way you want.

The steps are:

**1)** create your dummy columns with `pd.get_dummies`, only for the rows in which the column you are encoding is numeric. This is achieved by `pd.get_dummies(df.x.loc[~df.x.str.isnumeric()], prefix='x')`, for example

**2)** [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the dummy columns with your original dataframe

**3)** force your original `x` and `y` to numeric types, with `NaN` when it's not possible, finally replacing the `NaN`s with `0`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['No Data', '2', 'Testing', 'Offline'],
                  'y':['2', 'No Data', '4', 'Testing'],
                  'z':[1, 2, 3, 6]})
# Steps 1 and 2
df = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.x.loc[~df.x.str.isnumeric()],
                            prefix='x'))
      .join((pd.get_dummies(df.y.loc[~df.y.str.isnumeric()], prefix='y')))
      .fillna(0))

# Step 3
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df.x, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df.y, errors='coerce').fillna(0)

# output:
     x    y  z  x_No Data  x_Offline  x_Testing  y_No Data  y_Testing
0  0.0  2.0  1        1.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
1  2.0  0.0  2        0.0        0.0        0.0        1.0        0.0
2  0.0  4.0  3        0.0        0.0        1.0        0.0        0.0
3  0.0  0.0  6        0.0        1.0        0.0        0.0        1.0
```

Comment: Thank you @sacul. Is it possible to ignore the "numeric" values (though they are string types) prior to OHE?